# Why is there an Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, exception, input

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distribution{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("How many cards to be distributed? ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cards = keyboard.nextInt();
     }
}
```

When I run it, it gives me an exception in thread `main`:

`java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Comment: Because there's no such element?

Comment: @VirtualTroll:
Sorry, but that's unhelpful as I am a beginner and do not understand half of that. Also, please don't tell me something like "hasNextLine" because I never had to do that before.

Comment: @Dave Newton: This never happened before, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: sure you are running this program?

Comment: @Mingtao Zhang: Yeah, I compiled it and it broke.

Comment: The code you have works just fine for me (Windows 7, cmd prompt). It seems you are using a special environment that does tricks with System.in and doesn't support your way of using it.

Comment: It works fine for me too!! (on GCC)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call [hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) first,

```
public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("How many cards to be distributed? ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
        int cards = keyboard.nextInt();
        // ...
    }
 }
```

When I try it with your link to compileonline it also works:
[image: Working code]

**Edit**

The actual answer was to specify the input in your "STDIN" input line on your online tool. The code you posted works when you do (as indicated by this second image),

[image: Working code 2]

Comment: It won't let me input - it just does nothing!

Comment: @asdf Are you using another `Scanner` on `System.in` in your code? Are you closing it? Because this code works.

Comment: I'm only using keyboard. I don't know what closing is, but I don't think so. If it helps, I'm using http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: I just tested it. Works fine. Make sure you're putting the number in "STDIN Input:" and not in "Command Line Arguments:". Also, make sure you have a `main` method, it didn't when I clicked on the link.

Comment: @asdf compiling java online generally doesn't have System.in stream for you to input anything, so you won't get same results as running on your local computer

Comment: @eis This one has a line for STDIN Input. It was odd (but it worked).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch your code works, but the code OP has doesn't. The code OP has works just fine using a local cmd prompt though.

Comment: @eis I can reproduce the OP exception with their code and nothing for "STDIN", so I suspect that's what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much - I realized that I have to input the number in the STDIN Input box BEFORE I run the code!

Comment: Yes, you're right. However this answer, as it's written, is actually wrong - calling hasNextInt() does not impact here. Maybe you should write the answer to contain the information that the code OP has works just fine on regular env, but he was using compileonline.com, which requires to fill stdin before execution for this to work?

Comment: @eis Edited to add second example. It's always harder to perform root cause analysis when you only have half of the information.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes, of course. I didn't mean to criticize, just wanted to notify to get the actual answer correct now that we have enough information. That way the content (question + answer) makes more sense and is more useful.